# How to to access first and last name for the following user model (based on mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, request, body-parser

I am looking at some code, with a user schema, similar to the following.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
   {
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },

        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        profile: {
            firstName: {
                type: String
            },
            lastName: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Now, as far as I can understand, the top-level properties are email, password and profile.... `firstName` and `lastName` should only be accessible from within `profile`. However, the details are being accessed with something like the following.

```
exports.register = function(req, res, next) { 

  // Check for registration errors
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;

  // Return error if no email provided
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address.'});
  }

  // Return error if no password provided
  if (!password) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter a password.' });
  }

  // Return error if full name not provided
  if (!firstName || !lastName) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter your full name.'});
  }

...
```

I don't seem to understand why the `firstName` and `lastName` are being accessed directly with `req.body.firstName` instead of `req.body.profile.firstName`. There don't seem to be any virtual attributes in place either. So what's going on!?

Comment: How is this register route called? I don't see mongoose playing a part here. This looks like a route getting data via POST request.

Comment: FYI, `passport` is also being used. I just didn't post the code, because I didn't think it would be relevant. Anyway, this is also happening `var authRoutes = express.Router(); authRoutes.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register);`.... where `register` is the above method.

Comment: Regardless of that `req` is your incoming request.
Where is the part where this POST data is stored in mongoose?

Comment: @Grateful you need to set `profile.firstName` on front-end(client side) if want to access `req.body.profile.firstName`. This is not related to your monoose model

Comment: Oh wait a minute.... I think the penny may just have dropped! You are absolutely right. Mongoose is being used to model the data... however, the `firstName` and `lastName` are coming in directly from the form, and mongoose has nothing to do with the data at this point. My bad. Thank you Daniel, for pointing out such basic information. :)

Comment: @ArifKhan Thank you too. I realised what Daniel meant as you were typing.

Comment: @DanielKhan Would you like to post an "answer", so that I may officially select it...

Comment: @Grateful - thank you - I've posted a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an express application request parameters are passed in as first parameter of a route `(req, res, next)`. The sample code posted shows the result of a POST request to a route called /register.
This data does not relate to the model posted with the question.

To be able to work with the model, the data needs to be stored into a new Mongoose object.
So within the route one would write:

```
exports.register = function(req, res, next) { 
    const User = new User();
    User.profile.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    // ... and so on
    User.save((err, savedUser) => { 
        if(err) return next(err);
        // end request
    });
}
```

Please note that some kind of sanity check is recommended when dealing with user provided variables. Using it like in my example above may enable an attacker to store a string of arbitrary length inside the database which is most probably not desired.

Answer (score 2):

`req.body` added by [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and this is not related to your mongoose model. You will get data in `req.body` sent from front-end(client side). Apart from this issue, I would like to recommend you to use following format that may help you

You may like to use schema for [sub-document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

```
var profileSchema = new Schema({
   firstName: String,
   lastName: String
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    profile: profileSchema
});
```

and may use like

```
exports.register = function(req, res, next) { 

  if(!req.body)
      return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Unable to parse data'});

  // Check for registration errors
  const userData = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    profile: {
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName
    }
  }

  // Return error if no email provided
  if (!userData.email) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address.'});
  }

  // Return error if no password provided
  if (!userData.password) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter a password.' });
  }

  // Return error if full name not provided
  if (!userData.profile.firstName || !userData.profile.lastName) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter your full name.'});
  }

  var newUser = new User(userData);// you must import user schema before using User
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @DanielKhan, within the above comments, mongoose is only being used to model the data. However, at this point, it has nothing to do with the data coming in directly from the client. Hence, all the fields, including email, password, and first name, and last name will be retrieved at the same level... using `req.body`.